# How to axios get elements from an array

Tags: mongodb, next.js, axios

I have the next User table:

```
new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        email: String,
        password: String,
        })
```

end an Itinerary table:

```
mongoose.Schema(
        {
          name: String, 
          usersId:[ {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "user" //1:m
          }]
          
        },
```

The field UsersId will take multiple users Id's assigned to that itinerary.
I want to show on front-end all those users's email adresses.

```
  const [usersName, setUsersName] = useState([]);
  const iti = React.useContext<any[]>(ItineraryContext);
useEffect(() => {
    iti.map((dataObj) =>
      dataObj.usersId.map((item: any) => {
        return axios
          .get(`http://localhost:8080/api/auth/allusersId/${item}`)
          .then((res) => {
            setUsersName(res.data.email);
            console.log(res.data);
          })

          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      })
    );
  }, [iti]);
```

but I get an error at Get. I do not know how to extract data from an array.

```
exports.findUsersById = (req, res) => {
  User.find({
     id: [req.params.id]
    }, 'email', (err, user) => {
      
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      return;
    }

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).send({ message: 'User Not found.' });
    }

    res.status(200).send({
      email:[user.email]
    });
  });
};
```

UPDATE! It works but I keep getting undefined when I try to console.log(res.data). But in network, from inspect it gets the id s.
Maybe I don't return the data okay from backend
UPDATE 2: I change the controller from .find to . findOne and it returns only the first email

Comment: question. req is null ? also when you refer to get elements from array are you referring to one user correct? and this is confusing since you want to get all the users with given ids

Comment: sorry, but what is question.req? and no, multiple users.

Comment: request on the function... also do you really need the Itinerary table ? because with the user table should be fair enough to show a list of user on an Index page. Does it make sense ? unless you missed the ItineraryId if its a M:N relationship

Comment: I want to show the email from the users added in that itinerary by the author. So yea I kinda need that

Comment: please paste all the code involved and clean up the question description, thanks a lot

Comment: It has undefined due the async behavior uou can enclose it on a promise..but does not matter :) so you cannot iterate over several IDs correct ?

Comment: This is what I send in the api request [Array(2)]0: (2) ['648472aa17a505dc36ffb1b7', '648705e0c0a0395aa659251c']length: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)